# javascript function call through href?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call javascript function (without argument) through href it works fine but same function call (with argument) it through error unexpected end of input

```
infowindow.setContent("<table><tr><th>Name</th><td><a href='javascript:Institute('"+code+"')'>" + text + "</a></td></tr><tr><th>IP Address</th><td>" + ip + "</td></tr><tr><th>Code</th><td><a href='javascript:Institute();'>" + code + "</a></td></tr></table>");
```

Comment: how are you passing arguments?

Comment: Mashing together strings in JavaScript to make HTML with JavaScript inside it is a recipe for a headache. Don't do that. Use DOM. Use `createElement`. Use `createTextNode`. Use `appendChild`. Use `addEventListener`. Your code will be more verbose but infinitely easier to understand, debug and maintain.

Comment: I'm just being curious : is there an advantage of doing this in href instead of onclick event ?

Comment: @Quentin if it's a huge chunk of HTML I wouldn't advise using `createElement`. I agree that `addEventListener` would be a better option though, OP could get the best of both by giving the clickable elements an `id="some_button_id"` and then `document.getElementById('some_button_id').addEventListener(...)`

Comment: @Niko — No. It makes it more complicated. Should be a button rather than a link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
infowindow.setContent('<table><tr><th>Name</th><td><a href="javascript:Institute(\''+code+'\')">' + text + '</a></td></tr><tr><th>IP Address</th><td>' + ip + '</td></tr><tr><th>Code</th><td><a href="javascript:Institute();">' + code + '</a></td></tr></table>');
```

This way the result HTML has double quotes (`"`) for tag attributes and single quotes (`'`) for JavaScript strings, which is the best way to ensure no conflicts arise.

To demonstrate, this uses `document.write()` and `alert()` in stead but works if you click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>

```js
var code = 'The Code';
var text = 'The Text';
var ip = 'The IP';

document.write('<table><tr><th>Name</th><td><a href="javascript:alert(\''+code+'\')">' + text + '</a></td></tr><tr><th>IP Address</th><td>' + ip + '</td></tr><tr><th>Code</th><td><a href="javascript:alert(\'empty string\');">' + code + '</a></td></tr></table>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your quote.
Use : `<a href='javascript:Institute(\'"+code+"\')'>`

You could easily find it, if you use the HTML debugger from your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
infowindow.setContent('<table><tr><th>Name</th><td><a href="javascript:Institute(\""+code+"\");' + text + '</a></td></tr><tr><th>IP Address</th><td>' + ip + '</td></tr><tr><th>Code</th><td><a href="javascript:Institute();">' + code + '</a></td></tr></table>');
```